# Does a Hero widget rebuild its child after transition

Tags: flutter, animation

The flutter docs do not mention whether the `Hero` widget rebuild its child after the widget is placed onto the destination screen from the overlay.

Also is the state retained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hero animations work with having two separate widgets wrapped in hero widgets having a same tag. Tag helps to identify the widgets to be animated but they are two separate widgets and hence created separately.

So, yes destination widget is created separately during the animation process and so the state is not retained.

I hope it clarifies it.

Comment: Any way to prevent rebuilds during screen transition?